# Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'werkzeug'

Tags: django, aws-lambda, pip, python-3.6, zappa

I suddenly started getting this error on a Django + AWS lambda setup with zappa. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 image on bitbucket pipelines to trigger the deployment.

> Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'werkzeug'

It was working fine for `python3.6` on `zappa==0.42.2` until the last deployment in 25-July-2019. I thought it was due to some code changes on the app that's causing it (even though the code changes are not related to pip modules - just some updates on the application's codebase) but even reverting to previous deployments are throwing this error now.

My zappa config has a `slim_handler: true`

```
{
    "staging": {
        "project_name": "myapp",
        "slim_handler": true,
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "log_level": "WARNING",
        "timeout_seconds": 300
    }
}
```

I have tried some suggested solutions in Zappa's GitHub issues but without success.

- https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/64
- https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1549

I've also tried some SO solutions from questions related to import issues in zappa and haven't been successful. I would highly appreciate any pointers for debugging or workarounds for this zappa issue in AWS lambda with `python3.6`.

Answer (score 6):

For people who are facing similar issue

I fixed it by install zappa in the venv itself.

So, follow the steps (assuming you have venv in env folder locally)

```
$ source ./env/bin/activate
$ pip install zappa
$ zappa deploy or zappa update
```

Comment: can you explain how did you do that?

Comment: Just exactly as the code above